# Is Renderer needed in cd_dynamic_conf?

Tags: content-delivery, 2013, configuration

I've seen the following `cd_dynamic_conf` section in a few examples online (on [YATB](http://yatb.mitza.net/2013/06/writing-my-own-custom-rel-tag.html) and [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11265700/395495)).

```
<TCDLEngine>
    <Renderer Class="com.tridion.tcdl.TCDLRenderer">
        <Properties>
            <Property Name="prop1" Value="value1" />
            <Property Name="prop2" Value="value2" />
        </Properties>
    </Renderer>
</TCDLEngine>
```

The schema (`schemas/cd_dynamic_conf.xsd`) and [documentation](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2013/cd_dynamic_confcd_dynamic_confN100B0) ([requires login](http://docportal.sdl.com/sdltridion)) suggest `Renderer` doesn't belong. For example, I see in cd_core log:

> 2013-07-30 20:09:28,848 ERROR XMLConfigurationReader - Error while
>   validating file 'cd_dynamic_conf.xml' with schema
>   'schemas/cd_dynamic_conf.xsd'. cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content
>   was found starting with element 'Renderer'. One of '{Properties,
>   TagBundle}' is expected.

The custom  SDL Live Content [example](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2013/task_1F8D35C28DB848B1ABB1BCE859972173) ([requires login](http://docportal.sdl.com/sdltridion)) has:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TCDLEngine>
  <Properties>
    <Property Name="myEngineProperty" Value="myEngineValue" />
  </Properties>
  <Tags>
    <Tag Namespace="tcdl" Name="FooApp">
      <Handler Class="com.mycompany.FooAppTagHandler" />
    </Tag>
  </Tags>
</TCDLEngine>
```

In a related [ServerFault post](https://serverfault.com/q/401626) at least in 2013 and UGC TagBundle is okay directly under `TCDLEngine`.

**Is the `Renderer` node needed and can I remove it? Or in other words, does this control my setup's TCDLRendering?**

**Update**: Removing the parent `Renderer` node and just leaving properties seems to work okay (after restarting everything). <strike>The xsd might be outdated then.</strike> **Sorry, got this backwards--the old format is outdated, the documentation and xsd seem to be correct. See answer below.**

```
<!--<Renderer Class="com.tridion.tcdl.TCDLRenderer">-->
    <Properties>
       <Property Name="prop1" Value="value1"/>
       <Property Name="prop2" Value="value2"/>
     </Properties>
<!--</Renderer>-->
```

Examples appreciated but I'll report back any followup. I'd imagine we'd at least want to optionally use the Properties section.

Comment: My experience is that schema changes occasionally get forgotten when a new release is made.

Comment: I agree with @DominicCronin, but typically if you see such errors in the logfile and the documentation (or your working example) tell you there is a mismatch, you should report it to Customer Support so the error can be fixed (by a documentation or Schema update, whatever is appropriate).

Comment: btw. could it be that the properties section is only there for Nuno and Mihai?

Comment: Good idea, I've shared the scenario with Support. In this case the documentation and the logfile *match* and suggest `<Renderer Class="com.tridion.tcdl.TCDLRenderer">` *probably* isn't needed. But it seems significant enough that I'd rather check to be sure.

Comment: It is very possible we're getting and sharing the same setting (copy/paste error?). Though I see the renderer tag on both a shared training instance as well as my "personal" VM.

Comment: Updated answer--xsd, docs, and sample were *correct*, it was the config that was outdated. 2013 doesn't need this tag, so the validation error may show up in 2011-2013 upgrades. Keep properties if you need them, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A documentation defect was put in for this.  2013 GA cd_dynamic_conf.xsd does not have Renderer now.  The sample config file also does not include this anymore.  So if you upgraded from 2011/2011 SP1, the Renderer part is there but it will continue to work.  Just that validation error is thrown.  The doc defect requests the CD config upgrade section include a note about this so as to avoid such an error.

Amit Mehta

Comment: Much appreciated, Amit. I removed the unneeded tag and this matches the system.

Comment: Follow-up: this is described in (at least) the SDL Tridion 2013 SP1 Upgrade Manual that the `Renderer` section no longer applies, especially if upgrading from 2011 or 2011 SP1.